# Why does bash parameter expansion not work inside systemd service files?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, systemd

I am trying to use `systemd`'s `EnvironmentFile` and add an option to the command when it is set in the file. I have the following in the unit file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo ${PORT:+port is $PORT}"
```

which doesn't echo anything when I start the service.

The following works as expected:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo port is $PORT"
```

which means that the file is read correctly.

Parameter substitution also works on command line:

```
$ PORT=1234 bash -c 'echo ${PORT:+port is $PORT}'
port is 1234
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[systemd does its own minimalistic shell-style command line parsing](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) of the contents of `ExecStart=` and other parameters. This minimalistic parsing supports basic environment variable substitution but apparently not things like `${PORT:+port is $PORT}`.

You will want to prevent systemd from doing that and let the invoked shell handle it.

From the documentation:

> To pass a literal dollar sign, use "`$$`".

So try this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo $${PORT:+port is $$PORT}"
```

Or better yet, try this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo $${PORT:+port is $$PORT}"
```

because the type of variable expansion you are doing here is POSIX standard and is not a bash-ism. By using `/bin/sh` instead of `bash` you will remove an unnecessary dependancy on `bash`.