# systemd and copy (/bin/cp): no such file or directory

Tags: debian, systemd, cp, file-copy

While manually copying the file the following works, as below:

```
userx@x:~$ cp -rv /opt/test-bak/* /opt/test/
'/opt/test-bak/file1' -> '/opt/test/file1'
'/opt/test-bak/file2' -> '/opt/test/file2'
'/opt/test-bak/file3' -> '/opt/test/file3'
'/opt/test-bak/subdir1/subfile1' -> '/opt/test/subdir1/subfile1'
'/opt/test-bak/subdir2/subfile2' -> '/opt/test/subdir2/subfile2'
```

However, installing it as a system service returns the "cannot stat '/opt/test-bak/*': No such file or directory" error

```
● testcopy.service - test usage of /bin/cp in systemd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/testcopy.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-04-21 14:55:16 +08; 4min 28s ago
  Process: 7872 ExecStart=/bin/cp -rv /opt/test-bak/* /opt/test/ (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7872 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 21 14:55:15 userx@x systemd[1]: Started test usage of /bin/cp in systemd.
Apr 21 14:55:15 userx@x cp[7872]: /bin/cp: cannot stat '/opt/test-bak/*': No such file or directory
Apr 21 14:55:16 userx@x systemd[1]: testcopy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 14:55:16 userx@x systemd[1]: testcopy.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 21 14:55:16 userx@x systemd[1]: testcopy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My service file as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=test usage of /bin/cp in systemd

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/cp -rv /opt/test-bak/* /opt/test/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Journal shows the below

```
Apr 21 15:05:12 x systemd[1]: Started test usage of /bin/cp in systemd.
Apr 21 15:05:12 x cp[9892]: /bin/cp: cannot stat '/opt/test-bak/*': No such file or directory
Apr 21 15:05:12 x systemd[1]: testcopy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 15:05:12 x systemd[1]: testcopy.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 21 15:05:12 x systemd[1]: testcopy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You should set the type of service to oneshot as that type is only ensured not to already be running when started and not restarted when it exits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using filename globbing patterns on the command line, it's the shell that expands the globbing patterns to filenames that match them, creating a list of pathnames that is then passed on to the utility that you are calling (`cp` here).

The command that you specify with `ExecStart` in your service file will not run in a shell.  This means that the filename globbing pattern `*` will not be expanded and that `cp` will be called with `/opt/test-bak/*` as the single literal source path to copy.

You could try wrapping your command in an in-line shell script:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/cp -rv /opt/test-bak/* /opt/test/'
```

Or, wrap your command in a short shell script,

```sh
#!/bin/sh

/bin/cp -rv /opt/test-bak/* /opt/test/
```

and then call that instead.

Since I know virtually nothing about systemd, there may be better ways to do this though.

Note that if the `*` glob does not match anything (because the directory is empty), then you would have the same issue as before. An unmatched globbing pattern will by default be left unexpanded.

Personally, I would use either

```
cd /opt/test-bak && /bin/cp -Rp -v . /opt/test
```

or

```
rsync -ai /opt/test/bak-test/ /opt/test
```

Since neither of these rely on the shell doing filename generation, they could both run without a wrapping shell.  Not relying on a shell glob would also, in this case, ensure that hidden files and directories in `bak-test` will get copied.

Comment: tested the first method, modifying to:
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/cp -rv /opt/test-bak/* /opt/test/'

Works smoothly, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216780/why-does-bash-parameter-expansion-not-work-inside-systemd-service-files

Comment: @steve Ok, so it has some very basic shell capabilities, but filename generation does not seem to be one of them.

Comment: For best results when running the command via a shell, `exec` the `cp`.  Do not rely upon a shell doing this implicitly.  Chain load dæmons, rather than leaving shell parent processes lying around.

Comment: @kusalananda, I tested your version `cp -rv /opt/test/bak-test/ /opt/test`, which is not the intended outcome of this question, as it results in nesting the `bak-test` folder into the `/opt/test` folder. 

The example using rsync is a good option, thanks for pointing it out. I would have tried rsync next but I was stumped why cp wouldn't work even after triple checking everything.

Comment: @JdeBP, just to clarify, do you mean that creating a foo-cp.sh quote **shell parent processes**, then calling it in a system file is less preferable? 

I do hesitate to do exactly this, as it makes it more difficult to trace back what you did later on, as well as the possibilities of deleting the file by mistake.

Comment: @KoayChiangTeik I have modified that command now. If one goes into the source directory and uses `cp -Rv . destdir`, the correct thing will happen.

Comment: The shell command `shopt-s nullglob` May prove helpful in situations where you don’t want a literal * as a result of an empty dir.

Comment: @JohnHascall The issue is that that would make the source path for `cp` disappear, and you'd call `cp` with a single path, which would cause an error.

Comment: In this particular case, yes.